# Double Integral: Finding a suitable change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Here is a question that I am trying to review:

Perform a suitable change of variables to rewrite the integral $\iint_R\ xy^2\,dA$
 where $R$ is the region bounded by the lines $x-y=2$, $x-y=-1$, $2x+3y=1$, and $2x+3y=0$. Do not evaluate the integral.

I let $u=x-y$ and $v=2x+3y$.

The jacobian did not simplify nicely. What would be a suitable change of variables?

Comment: Well we don't know what "suitable" means, so how can we help?

Comment: Well, the transformation was not given. So I think suitable means I had to come up with it myself, which is the part I am having trouble with.

Comment: How about the change of variables $(x,y) \to (x,y).$

Comment: But $(x,y)$ is not a simple region and I believe would involve 3 integrals.

Comment: Because $R$ is a parallelogram, I think the goal would be having a (affine, or even linear) transformation $\phi$ such that $\phi(R) = [a,b] \times [c,d]$. So I'd recommend calculating the vertices of $R$ and with that two vectors that define the sides of $R$. Then you can easily find an affine transformation such that you get the required shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, its actually rather easy.

Let $u=x-y$ and $v=2x+3y$

So $u = 2$ and $u = -1$ and $v = 1$ and $v=0$. These will be our bounds for our new integration.

We can write,

$3u=3x-3y$

$v=2x+3y$

Solving for x by adding together,

$3u +v=5x$ implies $x=(3u+v)/5$

We can also write,

$-2u=-2x+2y$

$v=2x+3y$

Solve for y by adding together,

$v-2u=5y$ implies $y=(v-2u)/5$

Find the jacobian $|d(x,y)/d(u,v)|$

Now we can integrate with our new bounds. Solved.